# How does Facebook manage the user session?

Tags: javascript, facebook, session, web-applications

I'm kind of intrigued on how Facebook manages the user session in their different web apps (Facebook and Messenger). When I enter the Messenger web app, it knows that I'm logged in Facebook and let me use the app. I want to know which tecnologies would let me achieve that (Redis maybe?) or how can they share the same session?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`messenger.com` makes an ajax request to `facebook.com` and gets the information if the user is logged in there or not.

Once you are authenticated in `messenger.com`, you have a new session which is independent of the `facebook.com` session.

The request which is made can be seen in the Network tab from the developer tools:

```
POST https://www.facebook.com/login/async_sso/messenger_dot_com/?dpr=1&__a=1
```

This endpoint allows `messenger.com` to make cross origin requests (because of this response header):

```
access-control-allow-origin: https://www.messenger.com
```

In the `x-auth-result` the information about your Facebook account is sent in base64, and it's parsed using `JSON.parse(atob(...))`.

For example, mine looked like this:

```
X-Auth-Result: eyJ1c2VyaWQiOi....sd1EifQ==
```

Then they do:

```
var n = m.getResponseHeader('X-Auth-Result');
if (n) {
    var o = JSON.parse(atob(n));
    c('Arbiter').inform('messengerdotcom_fb_session_info', o);
}
```

`o` will look like this, in my case:

```
{
    "userid": "1000....756",
    "name": "Ionică Bizău",
    "secret": "P0....r",
    "persistent": true,
    "initial_request_id": "AfU...lwQ"
}
```

And then, they finally can display your full name in the button.

When the user is not logged in, Facebook sends a `userid: "0"` back:

```
{
  "userid":"0",
  "initial_request_id":"A6...YOd"
}
```

Comment: Great answer! Thanks for your time!

Comment: How they share initial data between two domains in browser?

Comment: @Qamar Exactly, that's right: `messenger.com` gets initial data from `facebook.com` (`facebook.com` being *trusted* by `messenger.com` in this context).